# What is the difference between project and thesis?

Tags: thesis, projects

How project and thesis differs in terms of creativity ?

which one is original ?  project or thesis ?
any formal definition for project and thesis ?

Comment: You have probably two accounts (maybe [_three?_](http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/65448/akarsh-kandala)): you can merge them in a single one. See the [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 3):

It differs by school. Technically, [a thesis](http://www.kean.edu/~roneilfi/How%20to%20write%20a%20thesis%20statement.htm) is a claim that can be proven or disproven, but, in practice, the term "thesis" is often used for a project (for undergraduate or Master's degrees). On the other hand, a PhD thesis is not just a project; it should advance the state of knowledge in a field in a way that can only be done by someone knowledgeable in the field.

My department is considering renaming our Master's thesis requirement to Master's project, to acknowledge that it need not be a research contribution.

Of course, even a project can entail publishable work or advance the state of the art, but it need not.

Comment: thanks, is there any difference in terms of novelty ?
i know that a phd thesis or masters thesis needs to be original
but does the project needs to be original ?

Comment: @RashidaHasanRupa Technically, all projects are original, since nobody has solved exactly the same problem.